# Backbone.Marionette - show method not rendering properly.. somethings goes wrong

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In my app, I am getting the show method issue. something is wrongly going on with my app. But i couldn't able to find that.

in case if i do like this my view is properly rendering ( but this is wrong approach ):

```
regions:{
  header:'header',
  content:'section',
  footer:'footer'
},

initialize:function(){
  console.log('initialized by layout')
},    

renderRegions:function(options){

  this.formData = _.defaults(options || {}, requireViews);

  if(this.formData.headerView){ //this is true.
      this.headerView();
      this.renderHeaderView();
  }
},

headerView:function(){

  this.appHeaderView = new AppHeaderView({model:this.model});
  return this.appHeaderView;
},

renderHeaderView:function(){
  $(this.header.el).html(this.appHeaderView.render().el) //working fine
  //but this is not workig: this.header.show(this.appHeaderView)..why not working?
}
```

why i use the "this.header.show" - nothing is appending to header.

Any one highlight me what is wrong i do here?

I have simplified my total process, and added in Jsfiddle here is the link:

[Live Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/xf7kf/2/)

Comment: if im not mistaken show() its a method on Region or Layout instance. Is this.header in fits this term ?

Comment: I have added 'header' element in my region

Comment: you should use a selector in region hash value like {header:'.header'} + could you please attach root code that has regions:{} inside ?

Comment: header is not a has a class name nor id, it's html5 element.

Comment: You can't do that. In order to define a region you should point to a valid existing dom element.

Comment: I believe 3gwebtrain is right - if his template contains a `<header>` tag, then by all means he is allowed to show a view in the region attached to that tag...

Comment: Could you please give any console errors, or specify if there are none?

Comment: @Sharadh, the main problem is, I am not getting any error.

Comment: @all.. Live demo added. please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code:

1. A view's `model` needs to be instantiated, not just the model class.
2. There is absolutely no reason for you to overwrite the `ItemView`'s render method with what you had.
3. Your order of operations is wrong. `show` can only be called after the `Layout` is in the DOM already.

Here's the main thing that fixes your issue:

```
var Controller = Backbone.Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize:function(){
       this.layout = new Layout;
       $('#wrapper').html(this.layout.render().el);
       this.layout.renderRegions();
    }
});
```

[Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xf7kf/3/)

---

Another option (and something I find myself doing often) is to render the regions using the `onShow` method of the layout.

Comment: Nice catch. I was about to mention 'render the view apart from attaching it in the initialize', but this is the proper, canonical answer.